# How not to execute a function inside a click event when I click the second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying making a tic tac toe game. I have a click button to choose 'x' or 'o', as soon as the button is clicked, game starts. I have another button to reset the game, in other words, when the reset button is clicked, it goes back to choose 'x' or 'o' and  everything is reset. My problem is, after I clicked the 'x'or'o'the second time, gamerunfunction() always run twice at a time. My code is like this:

```
$('#x').click(function(){
   gamerunfunction();
});
gamerunfunction(){
 $('#box1').click(function(){
   if (box1 is empty)
     do something here!
   else
     do something here!
  });
 }
```

So, after I clicked #x button the second time. if and else statements inside the gamerunfunction both are executed. How do I avoid executing the gamerunfunction after I clicked #x at the second time;

Comment: have you looked at jquery's .one() function? http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!

Comment: Now that your problem is solved I'm going to be opinionated. A button that only clicks once isn't very good user interface, maybe you could consider a different approach, such as using the disabled status by setting `disabled = true` which will communicate to the user that the button is no longer clickable. It also gives you the option to re-enable the button later if you want to allow it to be clicked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the `.click()` in `gamerunfunction()`, which if called more than once, you'll end up with duplicate events firing.

What you want is the `.one()` function.